# Selection in two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search

> Given two sorted arrays ￼a[] and ￼b[], of sizes ￼N1 and ￼N2 , respectively, design an algorithm to find the kth largest key. The order of growth of the worst case running time of your algorithm should be ￼ ￼lg(N1+N2).

The hints to this question say that there are two possible solutions:

> Approach A: Compute the median in ￼a[] ￼ and the median in ￼ b[]￼.
>   Recur in a subproblem of roughly half the size.

I have already implemented this solution (whose essence consists of resizing/truncating a[] and b[] to length k, finding the median in each, comparing them, and choosing the appropriate halves of the array — dealing with corner cases as appropriate.)

The other approach given is:

> Design a constant-time algorithm to determine whether ￼a[i] ￼ is the kth
>   largest key. Use this subroutine and binary search.

I am having trouble finding out how to go about this approach. I know that given only one array one can find if a given element is kth-largest key in O(1) time by simply looking of the index of that element. However, I am not sure when two arrays how to determine if an element is the k-th largest across the union of those two arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is the k<sup>th</sup> largest element in `a ⋃ b`, then there are exactly `k-1` larger elements in `a ⋃ b`. Assuming that the arrays are sorted in descending order -- you'll have to adjust the arithmetic if they are sorted the other way -- then there are exactly `i-1` elements in `a` which are larger than `a[i]`; any remaining larger elements in the union must come from `b`.

Consequently, `a[i]` is the k<sup>th</sup> largest element in `a ⋃ b` if there are exactly `k-i` larger elements in `b`, since in that case there will be `i-1 + k-i == k-1` larger elements in the union. So you need to compare `a[i]` with `b[k-i]` and `b[k-i+1]` to find out, which is certainly O(1).

Comment: Now I'm stuck trying to use this in some sort of binary search to find the kth largest element in `a U b`. I tried the following: I modified the algorithm to determine whether an element in array A is greater than or equal to the kth largest element in `A U B` and then binary searched across A, and if not found, do the same thing to array B. This has O(logA + logB) complexity. Is there a way to do it in O(log(A+B)) complexity?

Comment: @user2612743: Essentially, O(logA + logB) is the same as O(log(A+B)), because they are different by at most a constant factor of 2.

Comment: How did you get that? Isn't O(logA + logB) = O(log(A*B)) by the logarithm laws? How is this asymptotically equivalent to O(log(A+B))?

Comment: @user2612743: 1 < (log(A)+log(B))/log(A+B) < 2. Rough proof of the second inequality: 2*log(A+B) > 2*log(max(A,B)) = log(max(A,B)) + log(max(A,B)) >= log(A) + log(B).